# Does third party authorized application have access to private tweet? i am having issue with user timeline REST API

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter, tweets, twitter-rest-api

I am not sure about whether third party authorized application have **access to private tweet** in twitter **b/c** i am **getting error** with **{} (with status 200)** when i used **user timeline REST API**. 
[image: look this image.]

I am using [Twitter-npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/twitter).

```
//Initialise twitter client object-Twitter with keys
var client = new Twitter({
    consumer_key: config.twitter.consumer_key,
    consumer_secret: config.twitter.consumer_secret,
    access_token_key: config.twitter.access_token_key,
    access_token_secret: config.twitter.access_token_secret
});
client.get('statuses/user_timeline', tparam, function (error, tweets, response) {
        if (error) {
          console.log("error : " + JSON.stringify(error)); // error: {} 
          // i am getting error here {}
        } else {
             //  data 
        }
});
```

It does not even get proper error message, so how can i get, why i am not getting tweets.
**When** i analysed i saw :

- if the Protect your tweet is true in setting i am getting 200 with
  error {}.
- if the protect your tweet is false in setting i am getting 200 with
  tweets.

i have also asked in **twitter-community** about this [**issue**](https://twittercommunity.com/t/the-user-timeline-api-neither-return-protected-tweets-nor-proper-error-message/107225/3) , but did not get fully response.

---

i also tried it using [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) , i get

`{"request":"\/1.1\/statuses\/user_timeline.json","error":"Not authorized."}`

and if any other error come it give error with code and message for **example**.

`{"errors":[{"code":32,"message":"Could not authenticate you."}]}`

why it's not giving such in my case?